# Where to perform a View Record Create if the goal is to keep controller light?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want my app to do the following.

User A, creates a Room. User A is then added as a member of Room A. This is done in the model with a before_save to create the RoomMember record.

Now what I need help with is the following:

Whenever any other user joins the Room, I want them added as a RoomMember. My question is, where do I do that RoomMember.create in Rails? It seems like in the controller but I'm under the impression you don't want to create records in the controller. So where should this live/work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller is where you create models.  You just want to keep them skinny and not know too much about the internals of models.

If I were approaching this I'd use a `has_many :through` pattern in the models. I would define an `add_attendee` in the Room model.  Finally, I'd have a separate AttendeesController to handle creating and destroying attendees (aka managing people in the room). Something like:

in User.rb
    has_many :attendees
    has_many :rooms, :through => :attendees

in Room.rb

```
has_many :attendees
has_many :users, :through => :attendees

def add_attendee(user_id)
    user_ids << user_id
end
```

in Attendee.rb

```
belongs_to :room
belongs_to :user
```

in RoomController.rb

```
def create
   @room = Room.create params[:room]
   @room.add_attendee(current_user.id)
end
```

in AttendeesController.rb

```
def create
    # This adds a person to the room
    @attendee = Attendee.create :user_id => params[:user_id], :room_id => params[:room_id]
end
```

Comment: This is what I needed. thank you. Should 'def add_attendee' be under protected or private? in the model?

Comment: Also, where does 'user_ids' come from?

Comment: @AnApprentice - add_attendee is a public method. user_ids is a result of the has_many :users statement.

Comment: I ended up doing 'self.attendees.find_or_create_by_user_id(user_id)' thoughts?

Comment: @AnApprentice - yup, probably a bit better to prevent duplications.  I don't know if self is needed here or not. I don't think so, but if you want to be implicit it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: you're probably better off doing what you're doing already for the owner of the room in a `before_create` rather than a `before_save` so that it's only done on the initial creation of the room (not on any subsequent updating).

Now to your question...

The action of joining the room will be a click by the user on some link (probably a POST form/link).  You should map that to an action in your controller which does something like this (I assume they're logged in, and that you have `current_user` available):

```
def join_room
  @room = Room.find params[:id]
  current_user.join_room @room
end
```

Then in the `User#join_room` method you'd have it create whatever record(s) you need.

Comment: I don't think that the params[:id] is available in the Model

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the `params[:id]` comes from the view/form/link that the user clicks in order to join the room.

Comment: Indeed.. but the model has before_create and before_save, while the controller has before_filter.  In the model, how do you know params[:id]?

Comment: What are you talking about?  `params[:id]` comes from whatever you set in the **view** not in the model.  You just need to set your form to provide that `id` attribute to your controller.  Obviously I haven't shown the view.

Comment: @JasonKing - Sorry. Your first "As an aside" paragraph confused me because you started to talk about the before_create and before_save in the model then moved on to give the example.  I see now that the location of the join_room method is in some controller; probably UsersController. Sorry for the confusion.